# Android: moving through activities

Tags: android, android-activity, sms

I wanna know whats the best way for moving through activites. What happens if i call intent from child activity to go back in parent activity? Do activities accumulate in memory?

To be precise, in child activity i have a button for sending sms message. I want to go to previous activity immediately after the message is sent (or button is pressed), because I want to stop user from pressing send button again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the previous activity, simply call `finish()`. That will return to the last activity on the stack. That's usually the activity that invoked this subactivity, unless special flags are used in the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Android activity should be stored in a memory stack.
After the button is clicked in child activity, if you call function finish(), it should return to the parent activity.